# Get OAuth code from Codeigniter's SEO friendly URLs

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth

How can I get proper redirection from an OAuth site to my CodeIgniter site using routes?

I'm receiving the following URL from an OAuth site:

```
http://example.com/demo/beem/login/?oauth_token=abcdefghijklmno12n3n4n5n6&oauth_verifier=j2j3j4j5j6j7j89j1j2j3j4j5j6j7j8
```

**http://example.com/demo/** is my base URL.

When this URL is redirected to my website, it goes to the default 'welcome' controller.

Can someone guide me on using routes for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add to your `config/routes.php` file:

```
route['beem/login/?oauth_token=(:any)'] = 'welcome';
```

To redirect all the trafic from that url to your own controller called `Welcome`